# place-place-time

Tags: grammaticality, time, adverb-position

Could you please tell me which one of the following sentences is correct grammatically?

- I am giving a talk at the International Congress on Mathematical Physics in Berlin, Germany, in July 2021.
- I am giving a talk at the International Congress on Mathematical Physics in July 2021 in Berlin, Germany.

Comment: Less clunky is << In July 2021, I am giving a talk at the International Congress on Mathematical Physics in Berlin, Germany. >> Having three PPs together is rather unwieldy. /  I'd certainly avoid splitting the locatives with the temporal (your second variant).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : Thanks for your comment. What about replace "in July" by " from 2 th to 5 th July"? Can we say that "I am giving a talk at the International Congress on Mathematical Physics in Berlin, Germany from from 2 th to 5 the July"?

Comment: If there were no reason not to, I'd again front the temporal (2nd not 2 th). With your example, _Berlin_, I'd say that the _, Germany_ is better dropped (though with _Geisa_, say, it would need retaining). And  << I am giving a series of talks at the International Congress on Mathematical Physics in Berlin from the 2nd to the 5th of July. >> is fine (assuming you're talking each day. If not, << I am giving a talk at the International Congress on Mathematical Physics in Berlin, which event takes place from the 2nd to the 5th of July. >>

Comment: @Adam Please note 1**st** July = "the fir**st** of July"; 2**nd** July = "the seco**nd** of July"; 3**rd** July = "the thi**rd** of July"; 4**th** July = "the four**th** of July".

Comment: ... And '5th November', at least, and at least in the UK, is always rendered 'the 5th of November'.

Comment: *Picture yourself in a boat on a river with tangerine trees and marmalade skies in July 2021.* ;)